# How to use TeX Gyre Pagella in pdflatex for arXiv

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex, fontspec

Since arXiv still doesn't seem to support LuaLaTeX, I need to make my document work with pdfLaTeX instead. The only LuaLaTeX-specific stuff is

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
```

If I want the document to look as close to the one I compile with LuaLaTeX as possible, what do I need to do in terms of fonts? What differences can I expect? Is there anything in particular I should be on the lookout for? Are there subtleties that I really need to check in detail?

There is no other LuaLaTeX-specific stuff in my document, and it does compile fine with pdflatex once I replace some unicode symbols (but, of course, it looks entirely different).

Comment: your question is very unclear!!  If you just remove the lines you quote then it may work without error, but using different fonts (cm instead of pagella) that is either "something to watch out for" or "the intended effect"  depending on your unstated intention. Then other parts of your document may or may not have lua dependencies we can not know about. If it uses the `chickenize` package porting it to pdftex might be tricky.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. Updating.

Comment: You can `\usepackage{lfluatex}`, then do `\ifluatex <your current font stuff> \else <pdflatex stuff like inputenc, fontenc, mathpazo> \fi`. Then you can compile with either engine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you remove the lines you quote and add

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

then you will be using a different but more or less similar Palatino clone usable in pdftex.

Comment: Thank you for seeing through my unclear question, hitting the nail on the head :-)

Comment: Hmm. My $\chi$s have become Øs. Do you happen to know if this is a known bug/deficiency in mathpazo?

Comment: @gspr This works for me and makes [χ] in pdflatex `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{mathpazo}\begin{document}[$\chi$]\end{document}`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Your example does work here too. However, replacing $\chi$ with $\mathbf{\chi}$ gives me a boldface Ø. With LuaLaTeX, I get a boldface χ. Any ideas?

Comment: @gspr with the default definitions of `\mathbf` and `\chi` you should get a normal weight `\chi`  if you don't then you have redefined something. You won't get a bold chi from that as the mathbf font is a roman font with no lower case greek (welcome to the world of 8bit fonts:-)  you could get a bold chi using `\bm{\chi}` from bm package.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you! For the record, just plain `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{mathpazo}\begin{document}[$\mathbf{\chi}$]\end{document}`, i.e. no redefinitions, does in fact give me a boldface Ø instead of a normal-weight χ. I have mathpazo as it is provided by Debian - they might have changed something, but I find it unlikely. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @gspr _something_ has changed the definition of \chi, it may be mathpazo, not actually looked at the source of that since last century:-)

Comment: I can confirm the $\chi$ versus $\emptyset$ issue.  `\usepackage{bm}` followed by `$\boldsymbol{\chi}$` works fine.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` font packages, which provide Palatino clone text and math fonts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % Palatino clones
\usepackage{bm} % "bold math"
\begin{document}
$\alpha\beta\chi\bm{\chi}\delta\omega\sum \displaystyle\sum$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of newpx vs Tex-Gyre-Pagella?

Comment: @skan - In my opinion, the large integral symbol provided by `newpxmath` is far superior to that of TeX Gyre Pagella Math.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion for what it's worth is to use the Pagella package :

```
\usepackage{tgpagella} % alternative to MinionPro
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[centertags, intlimits, sumlimits, namelimits]{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

The result should also deal with all the math notation and greek letters.

Comment: What is the advantage of Tex-Gyre-Pagella vs newpx?