# How to create this gamma symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, blackboard

[image: Kindly help me to create this Gamma symbol]

How do I create this gamma symbol?

Answer (score 38):

A Gamma is an upside down L:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

\newcommand{\bbGamma}{{\mathpalette\makebbGamma\relax}}
\newcommand{\makebbGamma}[2]{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\mathsurround=0pt#1\mathbb{L}$}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\Gamma\bbGamma \mathrm{L}\mathbb{L}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would never guessed that...

Comment: That "trick" would ruin the document for copy/pasting, screen readers, search engines, etc.

Comment: @YSC Because copy pasting math works so flawlessly all the other times?

Comment: @HenriMenke Are you saying that since some documents containing a Gamma are already un-copiable, we should make all such documents ruined for copy/pasting, screen readers and search engines? egreg's answer displays a really nice trick; anyone which uses it should be aware of its consequences, though.

Answer (score 31):

You could use the package https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math and choose a math font. That way you get a concise set of glyphs (as long as the typeface's designer did their job well). You should also consider https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec for a coherent use of typefaces in math mode and text mode. The following examples generate serif blackboard bold capital gammas.

The following glyphs should all be the same (and they look alike to me).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
$\BbbGamma \mathbb{\Gamma} \mathbb{Γ} \symbb{\Gamma} \symbb{Γ} ℾ \symbol{"213E}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** You can also apply egreg's solution to another underrated font which blends well with CM and LM, please compare them yourself:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,dsfont,amssymb,booktabs}

\newcommand\BbbGamma{\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\mathds L$}}}
\newcommand\BbbGammaVar{\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\mathbb L$}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{16}{>{$}c<{$}} }
    \toprule
    \BbbGamma & \mathds h & \mathds k & \mathds 1 & \mathds A & \mathds B & \mathds C & \mathds D & \mathds E & \mathds F & \mathds G & \mathds H & \mathds I & \mathds J & \mathds K \\
    \Gamma & \text h & \text k & \text 1 & \text A & \text B & \text C & \text D & \text E & \text F & \text G & \text H & \text I & \text J & \text K \\
    \BbbGammaVar & \mathbb h & \mathbb k & \mathbb 1 & \mathbb A & \mathbb B & \mathbb C & \mathbb D & \mathbb E & \mathbb F & \mathbb G & \mathbb H & \mathbb I & \mathbb J & \mathbb K \\
    \midrule
    \mathds L & \mathds M & \mathds N & \mathds O & \mathds P & \mathds Q & \mathds R & \mathds S & \mathds T & \mathds U & \mathds V & \mathds W & \mathds X & \mathds Y & \mathds Z \\
    \text L & \text M & \text N & \text O & \text P & \text Q & \text R & \text S & \text T & \text U & \text V & \text W & \text X & \text Y & \text Z \\ 
    \mathbb L & \mathbb M & \mathbb N & \mathbb O & \mathbb P & \mathbb Q & \mathbb R & \mathbb S & \mathbb T & \mathbb U & \mathbb V & \mathbb W & \mathbb X & \mathbb Y & \mathbb Z \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Top row: `\mathds`, middle row: `Latin Modern`, bottom row: `\mathbb`.
[image]
My understanding is that `\mathds` is actually much closer to what someone would expect from a *blackboard bold* by just add a single double stroke on a blackboard than `\mathbb`.

---

The website https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/213e/fontsupport.htm# gives a comparison of various typefaces.

Comment: +1. With `unicode-math`, you can also write `\BbbGamma` or `\symbb{\Gamma}`. You can additionally use `\setmathfont[range={bb, bbit}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{...}` to use your double-struck alphabet of choice, including any TrueType or OpenType font.

Comment: @Davislor Indeed, RTFM (read the fine manual) is beneficiary. The new options the engines LuaTeX and XeTeX offer are astounding.

Comment: All of those commands produce the same output: ℾ (U+213E), but there is one difference.  If you `\setmathfont[range=bb]`, the `\symbb` command will correctly use the symbol from the selected blackboard font. I haven’t extensively tested, but I’ve noticed that `\mathrm`, etc. often keep using the main font.

Comment: Oh, and at least two other ways: `\char"213e` and `^^^^213e`.

Answer (score 14):

**WARNING**: Some long time ago there was some package for this, I do not remember the details. I guess it was somehow related to [this thingy](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/fonts/bbold/bbold.pdf). And I cannot really tell you why this was dropped, perhaps [this discussion helps you](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394965/121799).

Anyway, I kept excerpts of this on my machine and usually do something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\bbfamily}{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{bbold}\selectfont}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{bbold}{bold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbGamma}{\mathord}{bbold}{'000}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbDelta}{\mathord}{bbold}{'001}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbVarTheta}{\mathord}{bbold}{'002}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbLambda}{\mathord}{bbold}{'003}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbTheta}{\mathord}{bbold}{'004}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbPi}{\mathord}{bbold}{'005}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbSigma}{\mathord}{bbold}{'006}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbUpsilon}{\mathord}{bbold}{'007}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbPhi}{\mathord}{bbold}{'010}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbPsi}{\mathord}{bbold}{'011}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbOmega}{\mathord}{bbold}{'012}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbalpha}{\mathord}{bbold}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbbeta}{\mathord}{bbold}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbgamma}{\mathord}{bbold}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbdelta}{\mathord}{bbold}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbespilon}{\mathord}{bbold}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbzeta}{\mathord}{bbold}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbeta}{\mathord}{bbold}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbtheta}{\mathord}{bbold}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbiota}{\mathord}{bbold}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbkappa}{\mathord}{bbold}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bblambda}{\mathord}{bbold}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbmu}{\mathord}{bbold}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbnu}{\mathord}{bbold}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbxi}{\mathord}{bbold}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbpi}{\mathord}{bbold}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbrho}{\mathord}{bbold}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbsigma}{\mathord}{bbold}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbtau}{\mathord}{bbold}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbupsilon}{\mathord}{bbold}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbphi}{\mathord}{bbold}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbchi}{\mathord}{bbold}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbpsi}{\mathord}{bbold}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbomega}{\mathord}{bbold}{"7F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbell}{\mathord}{bbold}{"40}
\newcommand{\BBsymbol}[1]{%
\ifcat#1a\mathbbm{#1}\else
    \ifx#1\Gamma\bbGamma\fi
    \ifx#1\Delta\bbDelta\fi
    \ifx#1\VarTheta\bbVarTheta\fi
    \ifx#1\Lambda\bbLambda\fi
    \ifx#1\Theta\bbTheta\fi
    \ifx#1\Pi\bbPi\fi
    \ifx#1\Sigma\bbSigma\fi
    \ifx#1\Upsilon\bbUpsilon\fi
    \ifx#1\Phi\bbPhi\fi
    \ifx#1\Psi\bbPsi\fi
    \ifx#1\Omega\bbOmega\fi
    \ifx#1\alpha\bbalpha\fi
    \ifx#1\beta\bbbeta\fi
    \ifx#1\gamma\bbgamma\fi
    \ifx#1\delta\bbdelta\fi
    \ifx#1\espilon\bbespilon\fi
    \ifx#1\zeta\bbzeta\fi
    \ifx#1\eta\bbeta\fi
    \ifx#1\theta\bbtheta\fi
    \ifx#1\iota\bbiota\fi
    \ifx#1\kappa\bbkappa\fi
    \ifx#1\lambda\bblambda\fi
    \ifx#1\mu\bbmu\fi
    \ifx#1\nu\bbnu\fi
    \ifx#1\xi\bbxi\fi
    \ifx#1\pi\bbpi\fi
    \ifx#1\rho\bbrho\fi
    \ifx#1\sigma\bbsigma\fi
    \ifx#1\tau\bbtau\fi
    \ifx#1\upsilon\bbupsilon\fi
    \ifx#1\phi\bbphi\fi
    \ifx#1\chi\bbchi\fi
    \ifx#1\psi\bbpsi\fi
    \ifx#1\omega\bbomega\fi
    \ifx#1\ell\bbell\fi
\fi
}

\begin{document}
$\BBsymbol{\Gamma}\BBsymbol{\alpha}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

And of course the outcome is not as nice as in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452112/121799) but here you have double stroke letters for all Greek letters. (And those who feel like they need to shout at me: this post starts with a big disclaimer... ;-)

Comment: Just to add: I really do not know why there is no standard package for this, which also provides a non-pixelated versions of the `\mathbbm{C}` letters which come with the `bbm` package. By "I really do not know" whether these are legal or technical issues, or nobody feels if this something good to have. At least I would think this would be something good to have, and would be happy to spend some time to make this work. However, I have no idea how to design a font, and perhaps more importantly I do not know anything about the legal issues.

Comment: If you want to keep compatibility with other packages, `unicode-math` uses the macros `\BbbGamma`, etc.

Comment: @Davislor I stressed that I do not know why the package has been changed. (However, I would also not really recommend using `unicode-math`, but I kindly like to ask you not to start a discussion on this because there are simply different opinions and I am not sure we will find an agreement.) Anyway, thanks for the comment! I am sure that there are pitfalls and reasons why the old package has disappeared (yet I am using the above without problems in *many* documents).

Comment: I agree that this isn't the time or place for that discussion. I simply was noting that, if you use the same command names as other packages, it eases copy-paste and migration.

Comment: @marmot I would like to hear why you do not recommend `unicode-math` (generally?). I would like to learn from a experienced `TeX`nician of good reputation like you. I do not want to misuse this command section for a discussion, so is there a blog (or something similar) you might refer to?

Comment: @CampanIgnis I use LaTeX very often to upload papers on the arXiv. This seems to clash with unicode-math, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/272575/121799). I understand that this might be considered the arXiv's fault. However, I often wonder *why* arXiv does not support this kind of stuff. In my experience the people there were really friendly and seem to know what they are doing. Bottom-line: if you plan to submit to the arXiv, unicode-math is not an option, and perhaps there is even more to it. Yet some here are *very* religious about lualatex and I don't want that discussion.

Comment: @marmot. Thank you. So your statement apparently covers the battlesome topics `pdfTeX` vs `LuaTeX`, software engineering paradigms older than `TeX`, decisions made on arXiv, and its implications. I have some ideas where this discussion would head to.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend `unicode-math` for new documents, as CampanIgnis already posted.  There are several different packages that support double-struck blackboard-bold Greek letters for legacy NFSS, including:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}

\begin{document}
\( \mathbb{\Gamma} \)
\end{document}
```

Other packages including these symbols are `stix` and `mbboard`.

Comment: I have used your code for a colleague :-).

Answer (score 3):

this works as well:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcommand\mygamma{$\mathrm{I} \hspace{-0.4ex} \Gamma$}

\begin{document}

\tiny \mygamma
\small \mygamma
\normalsize \mygamma
\large \mygamma
\Large \mygamma
\Huge \mygamma

\end{document}
```

produces this result:

[image: Gamma]

it works also with other letters, e.g. R or N (real or natural numbers):

```
\newcommand\myr{$\mathrm{I} \hspace{-0.4ex} \mathrm{R}$}
\newcommand\myn{$\mathrm{I} \hspace{-0.4ex} \mathrm{N}$}
```

[image: R and N]

Answer (score 2):

I also like the `contour` package

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\newcommand*{\fancy}[1]{\color{white}\contour{black}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\fancy{$\Gamma$}
\end{document}
```

[image]