# Equivalent of mathbb for lower-case Greek letters (specially gamma)

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I'm trying to find a way of writing $\gamma$, and possible other lower-case Greek letters, in a mathbb-like style. What command/package should I use for that?

I tried the solution mentioned in one of the answers of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452110/how-to-create-this-gamma-symbol) but this does not seem to work.

The solution proposed in the accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/blackboard-bold-variants-for-greek-letters) technically works. But the font is not satisfactory.

So is there a package where the black-board version of a $\gamma$ looks good?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blackboard bold variants for Greek letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/blackboard-bold-variants-for-greek-letters)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Technically speaking yes. But the $\bbgamma$ in the package looks so ugly, that I will need to keep searching. I will edit the question.

Comment: There are various (math) fonts that support this character, which you can use with `unicode-math`. See https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/213d/fontsupport.htm for a list (click on _View All_ to see the actual character rendering). There are many different approaches in the design of this character, maybe you find one that you like.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for posting this link. The site is a gem.

Comment: @Marijn -- rather than closing this as a duplicate, your linked reference is worth an answer.

Comment: @CampanIgnis I see that my comment-converted-into-answer is basically the same as your answer in the linked question, including the link to fileformat.info - but I used more fonts :)

Comment: @Marijn I added the link after reading the comment so that future readers of my answer can benefit from it, too.

Answer (score 2):

The double struck (blackboard bold) lower case gamma is part of Unicode, as well as the upper case gamma, lower and upper case pi, and upper case sigma (but actually that is the double struck sum symbol, that happens to be a sigma).

If you have a (math) font that defines these characters then you can use them with the `unicode-math` package with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Various fonts have a different design for these characters, so you can choose which one you like best.

Code with some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\setmathfont{Symbola}
Symbola: $\mathbb{\Gamma\gamma\Pi\pi\sum}$

\setmathfont{DejaVu Sans}
DejaVu Sans: $\mathbb{\Gamma\gamma\Pi\pi\sum}$

\setmathfont{DejaVu Serif}
DejaVu Serif: $\mathbb{\Gamma\gamma\Pi\pi\sum}$

\setmathfont{Code2000-rdLO.ttf}
Code2000: $\mathbb{\Gamma\gamma\Pi\pi\sum}$

\setmathfont{STIX}
STIX: $\mathbb{\Gamma\gamma\Pi\pi\sum}$

\setmathfont{seguisym.ttf}
Segoe UI Symbol: $\mathbb{\Gamma\gamma\Pi\pi\sum}$

\setmathfont{Asana Math}
Asana Math: $\mathbb{\Gamma\gamma\Pi\pi\sum}$

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
Latin Modern: $\mathbb{\Gamma\gamma\Pi\pi\sum}$

\setmathfont{STIX}[range={\Bbbgamma}]
Latin Modern + STIX: $\mathbb{\Gamma\gamma\Pi\pi\sum}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This example is largely based on https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/213d/fontsupport.htm (click 'View All' to see the gamma character in the fonts that I did not include in the code above).

Note that `\setmathfont` changes the font for all math characters, however you can also set the font for just a single character using the `range` parameter, as shown in the last example. The codes for the range can be found in the file [`unicode-math-table.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf).